Incorrect css paths in laravel and vite
The problem is when i want to add a path in my app.css file in the resources folder in my laravel app, it doesn't work correctly, for example:
when i want to add a src value for @font-face like this: '/fonts/some-font.eot'
it searches for the file in this url: http://[::1]:5173/fonts/some-font.eot
but the url must be like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fonts/some-font.eot
so it won't find the file...
also my fonts folder is in the public folder.
How can i solve this?

Instead of creating the 'fonts' folder inside the public folder you can create it next to your 'app.css' file and type the path like this: ./fonts/some-font.eot
